# Animate text display on a textblock WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want my application to display the text to a textblock letter by letter, not the whole text once.

I tried to do the following:

```
        textBlock1.Text="";
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            DateTime t = DateTime.Now;
            textBlock1.Text += s[i].ToString();
            while (DateTime.Now < t.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500))) ;
        }
```

The problem is it waits for the whole time to pass, then it displays the whole text once.

I think there's an automated buffer or something to prevent doing that.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to schedule your UI update to be executed on the Dispatcher thread, your current update as you noticed will execute synchronously as a block which will freeze the UI until your update is fully completed. Instead you can use a `DispatcherTimer` to update the UI asynchronously letter by letter, i.e. with the help of an extension method:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= s.Length; i++)
{
    string partialText = s.Substring(0, i);
    Dispatcher.DelayInvoke(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500*i),
                            new Action(() =>
                            {
                                textBlock1.Text = partialText;
                            }));
}
```

With `DelayInvoke()` being an extension method for `Dispatcher`:

```
public static class DispatcherHelper
{
    public static void DelayInvoke(this Dispatcher dispatcher, TimeSpan ts, Action action)
    {
        DispatcherTimer delayTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        delayTimer.Interval = ts;
        delayTimer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            delayTimer.Stop();
            action();
        };
        delayTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: DispatcherPriority Enum is not supported in WP7

Comment: I made it that way, DispatcherTimer delayTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

Comment: @SherifMaherEaid: Fixed constructor call